# Is it possible to bind together controls, AppDelegate and UserDefaults codeless?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have an `AppDelegate` like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString *boundValue;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *boundValue;

@end
```

I will use `boundValue` for some real-time calculations later inside `AppDelegate`. In main `.xib` I also have `NSTextField` control.

So now I'd like to bind both `NSTextField` and `UserDefaults.boundValue` key to my `AppDelegate.boundValue`. And of course I'd like to do that with minimal code writing.

I have found the way how to bind `NSTextField` either to `AppDelegate` or to `UserDefaults`. But how can I bind `AppDelegate` to `UserDefaults`? How to wire these three pieces — control + delegate + defaults — together without additional lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a little bit of extra code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *boundValue;
```

Now you can connect in IB as you wish, provided of course appDelegate and userDefaults are represented in  main.xib  by those green and blue cubes.

Edit:
Here's quite a nice tutorial on binding user preferences: [Binding your preferences in Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/cocoabindings.html)

Comment: Nothing is changed… There is nothing in Bindings Inspector for my AppDelegate and SharedUserDefaultsController. Can you provide please some steps how to bind AppDelegate to UserDefaults (or vice versa)?

Comment: I've tried to add ObjectController for the AppDelegate, but it did not help me too… (as I understand AppDelegate is already bindings complaint in case of @property, so ObjectController is completely unneeded)

Comment: Whoa, slow down, don't panic. Yes, properties are bindings compliant, the IBOutlet keyword just makes sure the outlet is displayed in IB. The only reason I mentioned the object controllers is that it occurred to that you might have accidentally deleted them. By default, the appDelegate is already represented by an object controller (blue cube). Select said cube in IB and look at the Connections section of the info window: boundValue should be visible as an outlet. Now you can ctrl-drag between the cubes representing the appDelegate and the userDefaults. That's all there is to it.